# Proxy setting in windows via python

Tags: python, windows-7, proxy

In Windows 7 for giving proxy,

So, using the GUI, I would go:

Start → Control Panel → Network and Internet → Internet Options → Connections → LAN Settings

and then

1)use automatic configuration script

2)give an ip and port

Is there a command to do these tasks via cmd line (so that i can use it through subprocess)
Or is there module in python.

There is one in python 2.7 called _winrgr but 2nd part of the question can be solved using that.What about the first one?

Tried using netsh winhttp set proxy  but there was no change in proxy setting thought command line said that proxy has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the first part via _winreg.

```
key=registry.OpenKey(registry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections",0,registry.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
(value, regtype) = registry.QueryValueEx(key, "DefaultConnectionSettings")
if regtype == registry.REG_BINARY:
     value = value[:8] + chr(0x03) + value[9:]
registry.SetValueEx(key, "DefaultConnectionSettings", None, regtype, value)
```

A value of 3 mean use manual settings.
A value of 9 mean use automatic settings.
A value of 1 means it is not enabled.